# PSD calculation using seewave

Tags: r, power-spectral-density

I'm trying to calculate a mean PSD value from each .wav file inside a folder with many sound files.  I'm using seewave to calculate this but having trouble finding a nice result for my further analysis. This info will be used to characterize an urban soundscape coupled with other acoustic indices.

here is my R code:

library(seewave)

audio_files <- list.files("path_of_my_files", full.names = TRUE)

## PSD_function

calculate_psd <- function(file) {

snd <- readWave(file)

psd <- spec(snd, plot = FALSE, PSD = TRUE)

return(psd)
}

## create a list

psd_list <- list()

## calculate PSD for each file

for (file in audio_files) {
psd <- calculate_psd(file)
psd_list[[file]] <- psd
}

Here is where I get lost. How do I calculate and save the mean PSD value for each .wav file?

If anyone can help me with this I will be very much appreciated!!

all be best,

Answer (score 3):

Not so sure if you mean one singe value per file, that averaged the whole spectrum?? If so, here is a code that should make the trick:

```
library(seewave)
library(tuneR)

audio_files <- list.files("you_files_path_name", full.names = TRUE, pattern = "*.WAV")

#### PSD_function
calculate_psd <- function(file) {
  
  # read file
  snd <- readWave(file)
  
  # calculate mean spectrum
  psd <- as.data.frame(meanspec(snd, plot = F, PSD = F)) # (just because it was faster to run, change back if necessary)
  
  # name columns
  colnames(psd) <- c("frequency_Hz", "PSD")
  
  # calculate mean PSD (is this what you wanted??)
  m_psd = mean(psd$PSD)
  
  # return value
  return(m_psd) 
  }


###########################################################
i=1

# repeat (number of files) times... 
list_PSD_all_files = lapply(1:length(audio_files), function(i){ 
  # select file name number i
  file <- audio_files[i]
  
  # read file, calculate PSD
  psd <- calculate_psd(file) 
  
  # save in a data. frame
  PSD_per_file = data.frame( file_name = file,
                             mean_PSD = psd)
  return(PSD_per_file)
})

# transform your list into a data frame
PSD_all_files = do.call(rbind, list_PSD_all_files)

# save csv file
write.csv(PSD_all_files, "your_results_path_name/MeanPSD_per_file.csv")
```

If not, then adjust what is in the function `calculate_psd`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much lframond!! I will try this code. all the best! Martin.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted the mean PSD of a file, then keep the Parseval's theorem in mind

- PSD (power spectral density) is (Power/Hz) and the integral is simply Power
- this is equal to the power integral in the time domain
- the mean PSD is then the overall RMS value of your data in the file
- this can also be estimated also in time domain